# Bearer token not showing up in the request headers when trying to hit the API from react application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, axios

This is my POST service -

```
export const Services = {
    post: (url: string, body: IKeyValuePairs<any>= {}, headers: IKeyValuePairs<string> = {}): AxiosPromise => {
        return axios.post(url, body, headers);
    },
}
```

And I am using this service like below -

```
const response = await Services.post(`${Configuration.Instance.BaseUrl}/roles`, { roleName, description, permission }, contentTypeHeader);
```

Using contentTypeHeader as

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
const contentTypeHeader = { 
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
};
```

Somoehow on the browser, in chrome, no authorization is showing up -

[image]

Anyone any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Axios is expecting headers in the following format:

```
const contentTypeHeader = {
  'Headers': { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
  },
};
```